# How can I make a jQuery sortable no longer sortable after dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` with elements that we can drop to two sortable div's. We want to cap the target div to 3 elements, so that they can't add more. (But the elements should remain sortable in the target.) How can I do this?

```js
$(".fs").sortable({
    connectWith : '.fs',
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).children().length >= 3) {
            $(this).sortable("cancel");
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
 
$("#content .item").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".fs",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
})
```

```css
div {
  margin: .5ex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .5ex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
    <div id="content" >
        Content:
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 2</div>
        <div class="item">item 3</div>
        <div class="item">item 4</div>
        <div class="item">item 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fs" id="id1">Target 1</div>
    <div class="fs" id="id2">Target 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I've turned your code into a runnable stack snippet.  But it's not quite clear what your problem is.  I have no problem adding more than 3 items to a target.  And I've clarified your question about no longer being sortable.

Comment: I'm sorry, i see your reply today.

I want limit to 3 the number of elements in the target :)

Thank you Teepeemm!

Comment: Does my latest edit now accurately reflect what you're wanting?  (Also, you should prepend my name with an `@`, so that I get a notification.)

Comment: No, it's not what I expect. Sould not be able to put more than three items in the target.
Thank you for your help :))

Comment: I miss you @Teepeemm :))